# how to send output of fail module to file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have below part of my play for ansible fail module I want to redirect output of this module to file

```
     - name:
       fail:
         msg: "SVRELOAD NOT DONE ON THIS PTS {{ ansible_hostname }}"
       when: last_restart_date.stdout != ansible_date_time.date
       register: failed_task
```

Comment: You should therefore write the message to a log file (e.g. add a line at the end of a file somewhere) in a previous task before failing.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Also this not work with me
msg: "SVRELOAD NOT DONE ON THIS PTS {{ ansible_hostname }}" >> /tmp/ansible_fail.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it ( a little different approach). Just to demo the solution, I tried to download a package that does not exist. And I captured that message, and wrote in a file. you will have to adjust your play book with block and rescues.

Playbook ( with block, rescue )

```
---
- name: writing error to a file
  hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: block to create block-rescue-always
    block:
    - name: this module intentionally fails
      yum: name=does_not_exist state=latest
      register: failed_msg
    rescue:
    - name: write the error to a file
      debug: msg="failed with yum block"
    - name: create an error file
      file:
        path: /home/user1/ansible/error-msg.txt
        owner: user1
        group: user1
        mode: '0755'
        state: touch

    - name: write to a file with lineinfile
      lineinfile:
        path: /home/user1/ansible/error-msg.txt
        line: "{{ failed_msg }}"
```

and here is the response in the file `error-msg.txt`

```
{'msg': "No package matching 'does_not_exist' is available", 'failed': True, 'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {'pkg_mgr': 'apt'}}
```

you don't have to create a new file if your error file already exists with write permissions.